# Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'cypress-await' from

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'cypress-await' from '/private/var/folders/x6/q6c584hd10v7jwd_9rywn5m40000gn/T/09de0a49-817e-404a-97a9-01388d7c86c6/e2e.js.js

I am adding async await in cypress using plugin "cypress-await" but facing this issue. Can somebody help ?

[image]

[image]

I installed cypress await plugin from cypress
Expected was to wait for the element to be visible but facing the error as above

Comment: Please never post code as images, simply copy/paste your code into the question and format it as code. If you need any help, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in the plugin.

Please see [Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module #32](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-await/issues/32)

You should watch this issue, it would not be resolved simply or with work-around given that the plugin author is already aware of it.

I suggest you revert to an earlier version of Cypress if you really must use, or just use conventional test patterns since this plugin is syntactic sugar.

You will find many more examples and documentation if you stick to standard Cypress patterns.